# CURLOPT_SSLVERSION on my webserver

Tags: ssl, curl, paypal

i have a site with paypal payment method, when user try to pay the following error is displayed :

```
curl_error: 35
SSL connect error
```

I use curl to make paypal call :

```
ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1); 

//turning off the server and peer verification(TrustManager Concept)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/Certs/api_cert_chain.crt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers_array = paypal_adaptive_setupHeaders();
if (!empty($sandboxEmailAddress)) {
    $headers_array[] = "X-PAYPAL-SANDBOX-EMAIL-ADDRESS: " . $sandboxEmailAddress;
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers_array);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

So i have two questions

1- how can i solve this issue ?

```
adding : PPHttpConfig::$DEFAULT_CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = 4; cause 500 server error
```

2- Is there a way to know the CURLOPT_SSLVERSION used on my webserver? (dedicated server and i can access all privileges to install update things ...)
3- updating OPEN SSL can solve this?

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cURL error 35 is `CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR` which states:

> A problem occurred somewhere in the SSL/TLS handshake. You really want
>   the error buffer and read the message there as it pinpoints the
>   problem slightly more. Could be certificates (file formats, paths,
>   permissions), passwords, and others.

This is probably 1 of 2 things given recent changes PayPal made.

1. Your version of cURL/OpenSSL do not support TLS (several months ago PayPal stopped supporting SSLv3 and below which broke a lot of clients).  Since you've disabled peer verification, this might be the issue.
2. The `api_cert_chain.crt` no longer contains the correct certificate authority certificate PayPal is using.

Comment: true, i updated openssl and curl version, it works perfectly now thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

There is a leaflet of information on paypal about the security upgrade and the protocols your server has to support to communicate with PayPal.
Here is the link of the information page : https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1913&viewlocale=en_US#TLS

You have to make sure that openssl and Curl have the correct version on your server to be enable to  establish the connection.

Apparently you should have the following requirements :
- openssl version >= 1.0.1
- curl version >= 7.34.0.